# Position_dodge is not working as expected

Tags: r

I wanted to make bar chart which each currency has three bar(CV_before, CV_after, CV_all) using R.
This code below produce bar chart with one bar for each currency.
I tried to solve it by myself but I couldn't find any solutions so could you please help me.

```
ggplot(data = CV_before_after_Covid19) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = currency, y = CV_before, fill = "CV_before"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = currency, y = CV_after, fill = "CV_after"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = currency, y = CV_all, fill = "CV_all"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("CV_before" = "red", "CV_after" = "blue", "CV_all" = "purple")) +
  xlab("Currency") +
  ylab("Coefficient of variation") +
  ggtitle("Grouped Bar Chart of CV for currencies Before and After COVID-19")
```

[this is the table I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOy9O.png)

I tied to change width and google and ask chat GPT but I coudn't find answer to solve this problem.

Comment: And welcome to SO Haruki. In future, please use `dput(CV_before_after_Covid19)` and add the result to your question rather than posting an image of your data. Images cost a lot more to host than text. It also makes it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: As @leroy-tyrone's answer shows, separate ggplot layers do not interact with other layers, so if you want the positioning of three series to relate to each other, they should be specified as a single layer with different groups that can be dodged from each other.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your dataframe to work for `ggplot2` rather than try and make `ggplot2` work for your data. To achieve what you want, you need to have all your numeric y-axis values in one column. One way to do this is using `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Dataframe based on your sample image
df <- read.table(text = "currency   CV_all  CV_before   CV_after
CNY_X   0.04054334  0.03803299  0.041694824
EUR_X   0.05526912  0.03501674  0.062215616
IDR_X   0.03558016  0.02886830  0.036147174
INR_X   0.05557534  0.03831957  0.038223465
JPY_X   0.09165166  0.01969833  0.108483693
KHR_X   0.01056078  0.01396010  0.009620803
KRW_X   0.06563164  0.03785110  0.066604745
MMK_X   0.14419264  0.05973349  0.160856857
SGD_X   0.01980122  0.01577686  0.021311649
", header = T)

# Pivot your data to 'long' format
CV_before_after_Covid19 <- df %>%
  # Pivot every column except for currency
  pivot_longer(!currency) %>%
  # Set factor levels for new "name" column so the bars are in "intuitive" order
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("CV_before", "CV_after", "CV_all")))

# Plot the result
ggplot(data = CV_before_after_Covid19) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = currency, 
                         y = value,
                         group = name,
                         fill = name), 
           position = position_dodge()) + # Edited your dodge value so bars don't overlap
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("CV_before" = "red", "CV_after" = "blue", "CV_all" = "purple")) +
  xlab("Currency") +
  ylab("Coefficient of variation") +
  ggtitle("Grouped Bar Chart of CV for currencies Before and After COVID-19")
```

Result:
[image: result]